# how to use mysql Cluster in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to use cluster to implement a project with millions of requests. The server is written with nodejs and stores information in the mysql cluster db. Now, the client side with the Laravel framework needs to read information from the databases and display them.

The question is, how can I read data from cluster mysql in laravel?

Comment: millions of requests per second or year? As the number gets closer to the former I recommend getting a DBA. Data is read from the cluster in the same way (#include ultra large list of assumptions related to X cluster).

Comment: @danblack   per second !!

Comment: get a dba, don't prematurely optimize.